# How can I do consecutive destructive addition/subtraction?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.9

**Edit** Previous version of the question was not accurately reflecting my problem. I edited it.

I want to do a sequence of destructive addition/subtraction (to mutable objects that have the corresponding methods). After `a` is assigned by:

```
a = [:a, :b]
```

all of the following return a syntax error.

```
a -= [:b] += [:c]
(a -= [:b]) += [:c]
a.-=([:b]).+=([:c])
```

Is there a way to do it correctly, or does it not make sense to do this?

Comment: I don't even understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Theo I edited my question. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
a = [:a, :b]
a -= [:a]
```

is **not destructive** operation. What it really means is

```
a = a - [:a]
```

If you really want to chain destructive operations, you can, but you may need to create your own methods on base of existing destructive methods:

```
class Array
  def my_delete(e)
    delete(e)
    self
  end
end

[:a, :b].my_delete(:b).concat([:c])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an array literal, e.g. `[:b] += [:c]` is a syntax error, just like `[:b] = [:c]` would be. The left hand side must be a variable name, or something that will be rewritten as a method call (e.g. `[]=`).